# Integrating via Intent vs. Direct Integration in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

It seems to me that there are a lot of posts on here about integrating with intent (particularly in reference to ZXing's barcode scanner), and how it's much simpler than directly integrating the app into your own (i.e. not having to download and install the other app). I'm currently wondering:

1) When you integrate with intent, which part of the code automatically closes the intent integrated app once you are done using it? For example, if I've created a barcode scanner, once I've scanned the barcode, I'm free to manipulate it, and the ZXing app has been automatically closed, which is useful (because it saves memory).

2) Is there a way to integrate the app such that it will continue to be updated when ZXing updates their own app, but doesn't require a separate download of the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Android automatically manages memory, and can decide to terminate other applications based on its own criteria (explained in broad terms in the [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) section of the documentation). You shouldn't need to worry about this (except, of course, as it relates to your **own** app - i.e. saving state, &c).
2. No. If you add the classes of ZXing (or indeed, any others) as part of your code, then they are exactly that -- part of your code. They will only be updated when you publish a new version of your application, if you decide to reintegrate their changes.